# How to verbose Flask Template Errors?

Tags: python, flask

Sometimes, in my templates, if i have some wrong for loops (misstypos or whatever) my flask template render as `{}`. (Thats what i get on the browser screen).

In the long run this got annoyng, as its hard to find the issue.

Im running with `app.run(debug=True)` still cant figure out how to flask inform me whats wrong, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on windows, when setting up the environment

```
'set FLASK_ENV=development
```

Check here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/